# Trying to use Holt-Winters and SARIMA to fit this data

Tags: time-series, arima, seasonality

I want to find a time series model for monthly precipitation data.

I checked SARIMA and Holt-winters seasonal multiplicative models.

I can't find an appropriate model. These models underestimate high precipitation.

I have 528 monthly precipitation observations. I used the initial 420 observations for modeling and 108 observations to verification.

I added 1 to my data (because there are zeroes in my data) and then take the data to the power $\lambda=0.217$ (to transform data).

Please help me!
[image]

I upload my data to this link: 
http://up.persianscript.ir/uploads/f44c-data.rar

Comment: Could you do a plot of your data, perhaps? A time series plot, plus any other plots you think might be relevant?

Comment: I Couldn't find an option to attach the time series plot of my data. How  can I attach a file to this site?

Comment: You should be able to open the post for editing and click the image icon at the top of the window. If that doesn't work,  upload your plot to imgur.com, and paste the link to it and we can fix it for you.